# What is the appropriate way to get items from an entityqueue?

Tags: 8

I was having trouble finding API examples for entityqueue in Drupal 8.

I ended up writing a query to get the items.

```
$query = $this->database->select('entity_subqueue__items', 'esi')
  ->fields('esi', array('items_target_id'))
  ->condition('esi.bundle', $name_of_queue)
  ->orderBy('delta', 'ASC');

$nids = $query->execute()->fetchCol();
```

But I'd like to use a built in function if possible. Where's the function for retrieving items from an entity queue?

Comment: The same as in D7 - \Drupal::queue('my queue')->claimItem()

Comment: I don't think that's the same.  There's a table queue, that uses the DatabaseQueue object.  This is entityqueue module.  I tried your example, and it doesn't work, and digging into the code, it looks like DatabaseQueue object is looking at a table with columns such as "name", which are missing from the entity_subqueue__items table.

Comment: Ah sorry, I don't use entityqueue module.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Given $sid is your subqueue id:

```
$entity_subqueue = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('entity_subqueue')->load($sid);
```

Loads the subqueue object.  You can manipulate this to retrieve or update your entityqueue.

To get the items:

```
$items = $entity_subqueue->get('items')->getValue();
```

To update the items, add another item to the $items array and then save the entity object:

```
$items[] = ['target_id' => 69];

$entity_subqueue->set('items', $items);

$entity_subqueue->save();
```

Voila!

You can check in the database that your entity queue is updated:

```
select * from entity_subqueue__items where bundle = :sid;
```

I would like to also add that there is a great alternative to using entityqueue in Drupal 8: the [Config Pages](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_pages) module.  It allows you to create entity bundles that have only one entity.  You can then add any field type you like, including entity reference fields.  I recently replaced an entity queue on a project with a config page with an entity reference field, and I preferred the user experience.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a shortcut to load the subqueue: `\Drupal\entityqueue\Entity\EntitySubqueue::load($sid);`

Answer (score 0):

Based on what oknate says, you can also load the entities referenced directly:

```
$entity_subqueue = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('entity_subqueue')->load($sid);
$items = $entity_subqueue->get('items')->referencedEntities();
```